# Lagrange Multipliers for two constraints, degenerate case

Tags: convex-optimization

The [original post](http://Not%20sure%20but%20guessing%20this%20so%20Let%20C%20be%20a%20linear%20code%20in%20Fq%20and%20u%20%E2%88%88%20Fq%20.%20If%20v%20is%20an%20element%20of%20the%20coset%20u%20+%20C,%20then%20v%20+%20C%20=%20u%20+%20C.%20Proof.%20Since%20v%20%E2%88%88%20u+C,%20then%20v%20=%20u+x%20for%20some%20x%20%E2%88%88%20C.%20Consider%20any%20vector%20v+y%20%E2%88%88%20v+C,%20with%20y%20%E2%88%88%20C.%20Then%20v%20+%20y%20=%20(u%20+%20x)%20+%20y%20=%20u%20+%20(x%20+%20y)%20%E2%88%88%20u%20+%20C,%20so%20v+C%20%E2%8A%82%20u+C.%20Furthermore%20u%20=%20v+(%E2%88%92x)%20%E2%88%88%20v+C,%20so%20the%20same%20argument%20implies%20u+C%E2%8A%82v+C.%20Hencev+C=u+C.).

I was suggested to ask the question here.

To optimize $f(x,y,z)$ subject to $g(x,y,z)=h(x,y,z)=0$, we use the Lagrange Multiplier method and solve
\begin{equation*}
\nabla f=\lambda \nabla g+\mu\nabla h,\quad g=0,\quad h=0.
\end{equation*}
Geometrically, $\nabla f$ must lie on the normal plane spanned by $\nabla g$ and $\nabla h$. However, it can happen that $\nabla g$ is parallel to $\nabla h$ at certain points, and hence they cannot span the normal plane. In this case, does $\nabla f$ have to be parallel to $\nabla g$ to be a critical point? If yes, how to explain it? If no, can it happen that some critical points are missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following example: We are looking for the min of the function
$$f(x,y,z):=y$$
under the constraints
$$G(x,y,z):=x^6-z=0,\qquad H(x,y,z):=y^3-z=0\ .\tag{1}$$
It is easy to see that $(1)$ describes the set
$$S:=\bigl\{(x,y,z)\bigm|x\in{\mathbb R}, \ y=x^2, \ z=x^6\bigr\}\ ,$$
so that it is sufficient to consider the pullback
$$\psi(x):=f(x,x^2,x^6)=x^2\qquad(-\infty<x<\infty)\ .$$
The function $\psi$ is minimal at $x=0$, hence the minimum of $f$ on $S$ is taken at the origin ${\bf 0}$.

If we try to do the same problem with Lagrange's method we get nothing. The reason is the following: The tangent space $T$ of $S$ at ${\bf 0}$ is the $x$-axis. But $$\nabla G(0,0,0)=\nabla H(0,0,0)=(0,0,-1)$$ do not span the full orthogonal complement of $T$. Note that in the proof of Lagrange's method it is *assumed* that the two surfaces $G=0$ and $H=0$ *intersect transversally* at each point ${\bf p}\in S$, but this is not the case at ${\bf 0}$.

Comment: I got $(0,1,0)=\lambda(6x^5,0,-1)+\mu(0,3y^2,-1)$, together with $G=H=0$. Now if $x\neq 0$, $\lambda=0=\mu$ but $\mu\cdot 3y^2=1$ cannot hold; if $x=0=y=z$, again $\mu\cdot 3y^2=1$ cannot hold. So Lagrange's method has no real solution?

Comment: I agree, so the critical point is missing, right?